# ansible: gather facts in a task?

Tags: ansible

Right now in order to pull in ELK servers I have. Something like this for my main web app playbook

```
---

- hosts: elk
  gather_facts: true
  tags: ['apps']

- hosts: apps
  become: true
  roles:
    - common
    - app
  tags:
    - apps
```

That works fine but if I do something like

```
ansible-playbook ./runs/app.yml --limit app-01.domain.com
```

It skips over the elk servers.

So filebeat is setup in the common role. Is there anyway in like `common/roles/filebeat.yml` to gather_facts for the elk servers so I can clean it up and not skip them over if I want to limit ansible run to a single app server also?

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/23687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### delegate_facts

[Delegated facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts) learn facts from some other host, even if that other host wasn't part of the play.  Slightly modified from the documentation example play:

```
- hosts: apps
  tasks:
    - name: gather facts from apps
      tags: ['apps']
      setup:
      delegate_to: "{{item}}"
      delegate_facts: True
      with_items: "{{groups['elk']}}"
```